# How to use the Search webparts?

Tags: web-part, search, newform

I want to use the search webparts for my NewForm.

I want to search through the titles from a list on the same sharepoint.

Is it possible to view the search results on the same form? Normally when having the search box the results open in a new window.

Thanks for your help!